# Hashed User concept in db2

Tags: db2

Is there anything called "**Hashed User**" in the IBM DB2 version 10.1? Please help required urgently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never heard of the term "hashed user".

If this applies to user management: DB2 relies on external services such as the operating system for user management.

DB2 supports hash joins and several algorithms are based on hashing.

Comment: Actually I found in my db , the list of users who logged in and the user name was Hashed User(External Auth.). So not able to get what it is

Comment: Hashed user or hashed user password?

Comment: Its Hashed User only

Answer (score 1):

I guess I got the answer. Its not a part of DB2. But its a feature of SecureSphere. As SecureSphere captured the user name as Hashed User and its a security feature of SecureSphere that when SecureSphere encounters user names it cannot decrypt it will put it as **"Hashed User"**.